# How do I link up the NLTK libraries to chatterbot and then use SentimentComparison?

Tags: chatterbot

I've managed to download the NLTK stuff to a local chatterbox data folder, but after that I can't find any documentation on how exactly to get SentimentComparison to work, or how to initialize the VADER lexicon (which apparently gets extracted from the NLTK) and then have the chatbot use it all for the output. 
Python 3.6.3 
chatterbot 0.7.6
NLTK installed here ...chatterbot\data\nltk_data
Q: Can anyone provide me with examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sentiment analysis comparison by setting the `statement_comparison_function` for your chat bot.

For example:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.comparisons import sentiment_comparison

chatbot = ChatBot(
    # ...
    statement_comparison_function=sentiment_comparison
)
```

Your chat bot will download and use the NLTK data that it needs (such as the VADER lexicon) automatically.

More information about the available comparison functions can be found in the ChatterBot documentation: http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html